# How to preserved Application Setting for new upgrade?

Tags: c#, vb.net

When upgrading my old app, how do I preserved those old Application Setting that had been set by previous app, so that the new app can use back the old app setting?

thanks.

Comment: can you update your question with the details on what version you're upgrading to and from? .NET 1.1 to 4?

Comment: Also, are you using an installer to upgrade? If so, which one?

Comment: im using .net 4 with ClickOnce Deployment (by the way, is ClickOnce good enough or do i need to buy 3rd party installer?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a MSDN article on [ClickOnce Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228995.aspx) which explains the approach taken by ClickOnce for migrating application and user settings when upgrading to a newer version of the the application.